# Redis Cache Shared Session Configuration

Tags: caching, redis

I'm trying to configure Redis cache session storage for my CD environments.

I'm following this document -> https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/walkthrough--configuring-a-shared-session-state-database-using-the-redis-provider.html

In that document, it is only mention to change the setting under tracking/sharedSessionState. But nothing is mentioned about the sessionState configuration in the web.config file.
i.e.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager">
      <providers>
        <add name="mongo" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
        <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
        <add name="redis" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis" applicationName="private" connectionString="sharedSession" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
      </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Don't we have to change this sessionState configuration also to mode="custom" & customProvider="Redis"

ex:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="redis" cookieless="false" timeout="20">
      <providers>
        <add name="mongo" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
        <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
        <add name="redis" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis" applicationName="private" connectionString="sharedSession" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
      </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shared session configuration is for Analytics

Ths sessionState setting in the web.config setting manages the Redis storage for your Sitecore session.

Instructions found here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/walkthrough--configuring-a-private-session-state-database-using-the-redis-provider.html